# Changed sort_index behaviour in pandas 0.20

Tags: python, pandas

The behaviour of sort_index seems to have changed. I want to sort by date for periods but it since I updated to 0.20 it is sorting by day of month. I've seen the [list of changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-sort-index-changes) but haven't managed to recover the same results. Any tips?

Thanks

[Gist - Pandas 0.19.2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/725e6d89c1663c080fe86a01b3d08c37)

[Gist - Pandas 0.20.2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7abf370a8b2f1d9c0c9902d852cb42ce)

Comment: At first glance, doesn't look like the API has changed from [0.19.2](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
 to [0.20.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).  Try checking `df2.columns.get_level_values(0).dtype` in each version.  I'm getting `dtype='O'` (not Period) in 0.20.

Comment: That happens because I string-format the datetime objects to return just the interval in day/month-day/month format. Your comment actually made me realize that I can do that conversion after and that works!

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @Brad Solomon made me realize I could convert to the string format I wanted after sorting. Although the string sorting behaviour remains, I now obtain the same behaviour.

Instead of

```
colnames = ['Date', 'Client', 'Value', 'OtherValue']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={c:v for c,v in zip(colnames, [col1,col2,col3,col4])})
df2 = df.groupby(['Client',pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W-THU')]).sum().unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
new_cols = [i.start_time.strftime('%d/%m')+
            '-'+i.end_time.strftime('%d/%m')
           for i in df2.columns.levels[1]]
df2.columns.set_levels(new_cols,level=1,inplace=True)
df2.columns = df2.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df2.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

writing

```
colnames = ['Date', 'Client', 'Value', 'OtherValue']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={c:v for c,v in zip(colnames, [col1,col2,col3,col4])})
df2 = df.groupby(['Client',pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W-THU')]).sum().unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
df2.columns = df2.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df2.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
new_cols = [i.start_time.strftime('%d/%m')+
            '-'+i.end_time.strftime('%d/%m')
           for i in df2.columns.levels[0]]
df2.columns.set_levels(new_cols,level=0,inplace=True)
```

solves it.